# Is there any tool to generate all possible valid/invalid inputs for a given regular expressions?

Tags: c, regex, testcase

I am asked to write test cases for a program which check for the validity of input against a regular expression. I don't want to write test cases manually. Is there any way to generate an automatic list of test cases to check the regex program?

Comment: let's say the regex is `.*`. Good luck

Comment: A program that generates all possible valid and invalid inputs may exists, but it is not guaranteed to terminate (reminds me of the halting problem). For example, for `/a+/` there are endless matching patterns: a, aa, aaa, aaaa, and endless non-matching patterns. I think you have to narrow down your specification.

Comment: There is no universal solution as other people have said, however (depending on your regex) you may have some luck generating _some_ matches. That's for sure. See for instance https://github.com/asciimoo/exrex.

Comment: @Pablo I want to generate a minimal list for regex let say [a-zA-Z0-9]+. I know that it is not possible to check for infinite strings.

Comment: @TanuJain hehe, the title says **all possible**, not a minimal list, these are two different beasts. Look at Stefano's link.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo Thanks but this only returns matching strings. I want a list which has both true and false cases.

Comment: Enumerating strings which a regex happens to match (or not) is very different from testing whether the regex matches exactly the strings required by the problem description.

Comment: Consulting the requirements that resulted in the regex as the solution might be a productive approach to finding appropriate matching and non-matching test cases. Ultimately, if you could generate tests then you could generate code and wouldn't to test it. (If you end up writing a list, to minimize the test code, use the framework's data-driven features and if it doesn't have any—or if you prefer—Approval Test or similar.)

Comment: How is this question related to C?

Comment: Finally, I used exrex for generating the test cases. Valid regex gave me valid test cases and for generating random test cases I used .* as the regex. Thank you guys for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

you can do it if you have a plan.

1. define types of data you want to use.  use rand() calls to generate data of each type.  (white space, numbers, ascii chars, upper and lower case)
2. make sure to hard code some tests that you know will always work and always fail as a baseline.
3. have your program or script manage the frame work of the auto-test and include the use cases you defined in steps 1 and 2.